# How to insert table element in html Document using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to update an html document so that all the contents of the body are wrapped into a table cell.  Let's say the original html looks similar to

```java
    String test= "<html><body><p class=default><span>my content</span></p><p>my other content</p></body></html>";
```

I want to convert that into,

```java
    "<html><body><table><tr><td><p class=default><span>my content</span></p><p>my other content</p></td></tr></table></body></html>";
```

I'm trying to implement it this way but it is not working as expected.

```
Document ht = Jsoup.parse(test);
String updatedHtml = "<table><tr><td></td>" + ht.body().html() + "</td></tr></table>";
ht.body().html(updatedHtml);
System.out.println(ht.body().html());
```

What I get looks similar to the content pasted here. i.e. the body content is showing up outside of the table cell. How do I fix this issue?

```
<p class="default"><span>my content</span></p>
<p>my other content</p>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html in the `updatedHtml` string is not valid - you've got two closing `td` tags, and that is the cause of the problem. Remove the first closing tag:
`String updatedHtml = "<table><tr><td>" + ht.body().html() + "</td></tr></table>";`

And the output now is:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <p class="default"><span>my content</span></p>
     <p>my other content</p></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```